# Ambari install script location(s)

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hadoop-plugins, zypper

I'm setting up a HDP 2.1 cluster with Apache Ambari. All servers run SLES 11 SP3. The setup fails if I select to install Ganglia because of some dependencies:

```
Installing package apache2?mod_php* ('/usr/bin/zypper --quiet install --auto-agree-with-licenses --no-confirm apache2?mod_php*')
Problem: apache2-mod_php53-5.3.17-0.27.1.x86_64 conflicts with apache2-mod_php5 provided by    apache2-mod_php5-5.2.14-0.7.30.50.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
  do not install apache2-mod_php5-5.2.14-0.7.30.50.1.x86_64
  deinstallation of php5-5.2.14-0.7.30.50.1.x86_64
  deinstallation of php5-xmlwriter-5.2.14-0.7.30.50.1.x86_64
  [... more PHP 5.2.x packages ...]

 Solution 2: do not install apache2-mod_php53-5.3.17-0.27.1.x86_64
```

Apparently the Regex picks the 5.3 version, a 5.2 version would be available though.
So my **question** is: Where is the install script stored, that Ambari is running here? I would like to replace the regex with the correct version of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about what packages are to be installed is stored in

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/GANGLIA/metainfo.xml
```

Change the value and restart the Ambari Server for the changes to take effect.